# jQuery not working in vue component when change route

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have an issue with jQuery script files is not working inside vue component but it working outside it, I found a solution to put all script files in script section inside vue component, but I'am using this code for every page.
Note : The jQuery files run the first time the component is loaded, but the problem appears when changing to another route using the `vue-router`.

Any solution for that issue ?

Comment: Does Vue have access to jQuery? Is it working with other components? Or is it not available in Vue at all?

Comment: @selfagency 
the jQuery is working well outside the component, but inside the component working only when go directly to the specified route, and when change the route it dose not work.

Comment: If you are using the same component on both routes you are probably making use of component reusability, therefore the component is mounted just once and the script is triggered only one time.
You can use the :key property in the router component to force re-rendering the component on each route change: <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
Of course, you will be missing the most important advantage of Vue JS besides reactivity, which is reusability.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write an example usage area.
When this happens to me, I usually solve it by using a short setTimeOut in the mounted area of the app.vue file. But I have to see your example.
For example;

```
 methods: {
      
        jqueryFunction: function () {
            //your jquery codes
        },

    },

mounted() {
        setTimeout(function (evt) {
            this.jqueryFunction();
        }.bind(this), 3000);
    },
```

Comment: I think this method works when I want to use the code once, but in my case I want to use the code on all components in SPA.

Answer (score 0):

Just use dynamic event binding instead of your method.
use:

```
$('body').on('click', '.your-element', function (e) {
    ...
});
```

instead of:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    ...
});
```